# Opensource real django projects

Tags: django, open-source, buildout

I'm trying to learn Django. And need something to go beyond Hello world and Polls tutorial. Could you please recomend any real project written in Django? Tried to search, but found not many.
Especialy interested in usage of buildout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My project, [Open Knesset](http://oknesset.org/), is a django based project that uses data scraped from the israeli parliament (the knesset), analyses it, and presents it to users in more friendly and informative ways.
We use buildout.
[The main repo is here in github](http://github.com/ofri/Open-Knesset/).

Another place you should look at is djangosites.org, they have a list of [django powered sites with source code available](http://www.djangosites.org/with-source/).

Answer (score 4):

[Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) and [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) is the two most popular django opensource project. You will learn alot beyond just hello world, especially best-practices.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/) or [Askbot](http://askbot.org). They are open source Stack Exchange clones and are Django projects, go to their sites [(1)](http://askbot.org) and [(2)](http://meta.osqa.net/) to see them in action.

Answer (score 1):

I believe everything on the Django Packages site is open-source: [Django Packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/)

Answer (score 0):

List of the open-source Django projects:

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoResources#Open-SourceDjangoprojects